# Jqgrid : pagination does not work

Tags: jqgrid

I am new to Jqgrid. I have a question about the pagination.

**JSP**

```
$("#jqGridTable").jqGrid({
    colModel: [
    { label: 'A', name: 'a', key: true, width: 120, align:'center',sortable:false},
    { label: 'B', name: 'b',  width: 120, align:'center',sortable:false },
    { label: 'C', name: 'c', width: 170, align:'center', sorttype:'number',formatter:'number', sortable:false, summaryType:'sum' },
    { label: 'D', name: 'd', width: 180, align:'center',sortable:false, summaryType:'sum' },
    { label: 'E', name: 'e', width: 180, align:'center',sortable:false, summaryType:'sum' }
    ],
    jsonReader: "rows",
    guiStyle: "bootstrap",
    pager: '#jqGridPager',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "asc",
    caption: "Result",
    grouping: true,
    groupingView : {
        groupField : ['b'],
        groupColumnShow : [false],
        groupText : ['<b>{0}</b>'],
        groupCollapse : false,
        groupSummary : [true],
        showSummaryOnHide: true,
        groupDataSorted : true
    },
    footerrow: true,
    userDataOnFooter: true
});

$("#startQuery").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //reload Data from OperationQuality table
    jQuery('#jqGridTable').jqGrid('setGridParam', {
        url: '${contextPath}/analyze/quality/op-quality/query.do',
        datatype: 'json',
        rowNum: 4
    }).trigger('reloadGrid');

});
```

the data from server are 6 records.
There are 4 records show up on page1, but pagination does not work here.
Did I miss anything?

Thank you

Comment: Please include in all questions about jqGrid the **version** of jqGrid, which you use (can use), and the **fork**, which you use ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Indirectly,  because of the usage of `guiStyle: "bootstrap"`,  one can suppose that you use free jqGrid, but the version is still unknown. By the way the option `jsonReader: "rows"`, which you use, has wrong value. Please remove it of correct the value.

Comment: Hi Oleg, thank you for your reply, I am using 4.15.0 free jqGrid.

Comment: I also removed the jsonReader, but still does not work.

Comment: I tried to load the data from local ---> data:myData, the pagination works fine. But load the data from the controller, even set up page, total, records, not working...could you help me on this? thank you

Comment: Do you added `loadonce: true` and `forceClientSorting: true` option, like I suggested you in my answer? The demo in JSFiddle could use Echo service like the demo https://jsfiddle.net/65uwuh4o/. By the way the current version of free jqGrid ise 4.15.2.

Comment: Hi Oleg, thank you , it works!!!!   May I ask you another question regarding the groupCollapse?

Comment: You should post new question as new stackoverflow question. The goal of stackoverflow is **sharing common questions with other people**. Searching engine can good index *separate* questions/information. It's one of the rule which you can find in FAQ of stackowerflow.

Comment: I see that you marked **wrong** answer as solution of your problem. It could make some problems for other readers. See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47199264/jqgrid-pagination-does-not-work/47199685#comment81557935_47199685) below.

Answer (score 0):

jqGrid can be used in two main scenarios of the usage of paging: server side paring and client side paging. You use currently `datatype: 'json'` **without** the options `loadonce: true` and `forceClientSorting: true`. Thus, you use *server side paging* scenario. It means that the server should return *only one page* of data. The parameters `page` and `rows`, sent to the server, inform the server about the page size and the page number requested by the client.

If you want to return *all data at once* and you expect that the client (jqGrid) sort the return data and it will make paging too, then you should add both `loadonce: true` and `forceClientSorting: true` option to jqGrid.

Answer (score 0):

For the novice it is a good idea first to read the docs.
In case you use [Guriddo jqGrid](http://guriddo.net/) you may look at these documentation pages:

[Data - retrieving, mapping, configuration](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/#data-retrieving-mapping-configuration)

and

[Pager](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/navigating/#pager)